# Is there a way to have Windows 8.1 enter into a softer level of hibernation? So it still does work overnight but less hard drive activity?

Tags: windows-8.1, hibernate

My Windows 8.1 hard drive does loud things for  the entire night.
How can I put it to a softest sleep which would remedy this, without fearing to loose any data?

I really do not know what it is doing.

Anyway, hibernating it is too deep, something lighter would help. What software should I download?

Comment: Your best solution to this is to simple replace your hard drives with SSDs. No noise!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Right. But my HDD is 8TB large and SSD would be too  expensive together with a risk of data loss, is that correct ?

Comment: “…with a risk of data loss, is that correct ?” Your risk of data loss with a hard drive is a lot higher than with an SSD. But yes, an 8TB SSD would be more expensive than an 8TB hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the power plan.  This is for Windows 10, but there should be a similar spot in Windows 8.

1. click on Windows icon on taskbar
2. Type in `Power`
3. Click on **Edit Power Setting**
4. Click on **Change advanced power settings**
5. Change the **Turn off hard disk after** settings to suit

[image]

Comment: It works, but I have two more issues on this: after awaking the HDD my Internet connection is lost and I need to reboot the entire system Windows 8. Also I doubt whether my WD Goden HDD drive will not be "shocked" by switching it on and off every night and thus reducing its lifetime.

Comment: @user1766349 A hard drive being powered down once a day won’t “shock” it.